# Should a username be edited out of a title?

Tags: discussion, questions, title

Ran across a question today where the person asking it (who is also new), ended the question's title with "@user". Is there any point in leaving this in and not editing it out? Seems like the person posing the question was trying to target another user.

Comment: Even if we *were* a forum, name callouts in titles are generally not cool. That goes double for stack exchange.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the question title would lose no meaning without it, edit it out.

So if the title is `My FooBar breaks with a value of @j08691` then leave it in, but if the title is something like `My FooBar breaks, @j08691!` it probably doesn't belong there and can be excised.

Comment: It was definitely in the format of the latter.